# Using a Boolean in an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

## Program 1

```
list=[1,2,3,4]
A=3 in list
if A:
    print('True')
```

## Program 2

```
list=[1,2,3,4]
if A=3 in list:
    print('True')
```

So I have these 2 programs. Program 1 runs fine and I understand why, but Program 2 doesn't. I thought that since `A=3 in list` returns true or false you could just embed it as part of a if loop, but I guess not. Why is that? What's going on here?

Comment: You are trying to assign value in if condition. I think that's not valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603956/can-we-have-assignment-in-a-condition

Comment: This section from the official documentation will be useful - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditions where it states that _"Note that in Python, unlike C, assignment cannot occur inside expressions. C programmers may grumble about this, but it avoids a common class of problems encountered in C programs: typing = in an expression when == was intended"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments embedded in the program:

Program 1

```
list=[1,2,3,4]
# 3 in list evaluates to a boolean value, which is then assigned to the variable A
A=3 in list
if A:
    print('True')
```

Program 2

```
list=[1,2,3,4]
# Python does not allow this syntax as it is not "pythonic"
# Comparison A == 3 is a very common operation in an if statement
# and in other languages, assigning a variable in an if statement is allowed,
# As a consequence, this often results in very subtle bugs.
# Thus, Python does not allow this syntax to keep consistency and avoid these subtle bugs.
if A=3 in list:
    print('True')
```

Answer (score 3):

`if A=3 in list:` isn't valid syntax.  You were probably looking for the raw boolean expression instead, `if 3 in list`.

As an aside, don't use `list` as your variable name.  You're going to override the actual `list` method provided by Python.

Answer (score 2):

In Python assignments are statements rather than expressions, so they do not return any value. (more detail: [Why does Python assignment not return a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869770/why-does-python-assignment-not-return-a-value#4869838))

Answer (score 0):

its simple you can not use assignmnent operation in if

like here

```
  A=3
```

python will read it as assignmnent and throw error

Answer (score 0):

The first example is equivalent to:

```
A = (3 in list)
#i.e. A is boolean, not an integer of value 3.
```

Second example is just invalid syntax.