# Python - SyntaxError in --> if ((main_paned = gtk.HPaned())):

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I have a problem. I working in c++ and i dont know what i do wrong in python.

I have a c++ code:

```
if ((main_paned = GTK_PANED(gtk_paned_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL)))){
    std::cout << "created" << std::endl;
}
```

and i created this code in python:

```
if ((main_paned = gtk.HPaned())):
    print "created";
```

but return: SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
What i do wrong? And how to create add to variable in `if`?

Comment: Do you know how you would write that code in C++ without an assignment inside the `if` condition?

Comment: in c++ I wrote correctly, it adds gtk_paned to the variable, and if answers whether everything went well or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ version is using a side-effect to do both an assignment and a comparision at the same time. This works because the assignment operator happens to also return the value that it assigned, which is what the `if` is using for the truthiness comparison. To break it into two steps, it would be like doing:

```
main_paned = GTK_PANED(gtk_paned_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL));
if (main_paned)
{
    // rest of code
}
```

Python does not allow this behavior so you'd have to do a similar thing

```
main_paned = gtk.HPaned()
if main_paned:
    # code
```

or just

```
if gtk.HPaned():
```

That is of course assuming that your C++ code is correct, and you didn't instead intend to perform a logical comparison (`==`) instead of an assignment (`=`)

```
if (main_paned == GTK_PANED(gtk_paned_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL)))
{
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: It is possible to implement adding to a variable inside if? in python

Comment: No that was [explicitly disallowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603956/can-we-have-assignment-in-a-condition) by the language developer (Guido) in Python. In many C++ compilers, they will emit a warning if you do this as they think you may have done so accidentally