# Start Python 'while' loop before condition is defined

Tags: python

I've got a piece of code that executes a function, and then based on that output decides if it should reiterate:

```
while (function_output) > tolerance:
    function_output = function(x)
```

The problem is that the while loop won't start until "function_output" is defined - but it's defined in the loop. Currenly I've got:

```
function_output = function(x)
while (function_output) > tolerance:
    function_output = function(x)
```

but is there a way to get this loop to start without having to iterate the function once already?

Comment: Emulate a `do while`?  `while True:
  stuff()
  if fail_condition:
    break`

Comment: No, python has no "do"-"while" loop

Comment: function_output = tolerance + 1 before the loop?

Comment: @RobertHarvey of course, you can also just do what to OP is doing already

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: Which is why I used the word "emulate."

Comment: @TIF: For what it's worth, your second block of code is the canonical way to do it.

Comment: The OP is correct, in thinking that the 2nd way is bad: It has repeated code.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor meh. I find it better than doing an extra comparison each iteration. In any event, it's sort of a common idiom in python to emulate a do-while

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know a "do-while" loop was would I should have been looking for!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't see any extra comparisons, anywhere.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor the while-statement comparison and the `if` statement inside the while-loop body. Now, I believe the CPython may optimize `while True:` specifically. Not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing in python. Neither a `do-while`, nor a

```
while (x = f() > 5):
  dostuff
```

like in `C` and similar languages.

Similar constructs [have been proposed, but rejected](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0315/). What you are already doing is the best way to do it.

On the other hand, if you want to do it in a `do-while` style, the proposed way is

```
while True:
    if f() > tolerance:
       break
```

Comment: [soon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52722801/3620003)

Comment: @timgeb: useful (though a bit ugly looking). Let's  hope for a `do-while` too...

Answer (score 1):

Use a `break` statement to escape from a loop

```
while True:
    if function_output(x) > tolerance:
        break
```

Comment: I think your condition is inverted - that was the condition to continue the loop in the OPs code

Answer (score 0):

How about this pattern. You may want to choose a better variable name.

```
should_continue = True
while should_continue:
    should_continue = ( function(x) > tolerance )
```

Comment: While this is certainly an alternative, it isn't much better than OP's implementation.

Comment: @Idlehands is has less repeated code.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, What's repeated, a function call? If I had to weight up a repeated function call versus creating a new variable, I know which I'd prefer.

Comment: @Jpp I agree if just a function call, but if there are lots or arguments, the I would do it this way. Or encapsulate.