# How to use while(i = getNext()) pattern in python

Tags: python

In C++, I often use the following pattern:

```
while (int i = getNextElementPlease()) {
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

But in python I have to repeat call twice:

```
i = getNextElementPlease()
while (i):
    print(i)
    i = getNextElementPlease()
```

How to avoid duplication of `getNextElementPlease`?

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/

Comment: @roganjosh Actually I am trying to call method `recv` of `multiprocessing.connection.Connection`, while there is not `None` element.

Comment: I was bout to make the same suggestion as schwobaseggl below. The problem afaik is that it's considered _unpythonic_ to write assignments in conditions of `while`  and `if` (see the first comment [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2603966/305949)). So, you cannot translate this to Python directly.

Comment: @FK82 If it is unpythonic, it would be great to know what is pythonic way to do it.

Comment: @BhavinChirag `while True: ...` and `break` once your termination condition holds as described in both of the answers to your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either with the classic `while True`/`break` pattern:

```
while True:
    i = getNextElementPlease()
    if not i:
        break
    ...
```

or by using the [two-argument form of `iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) to build an iterator out of your function:

```
for i in iter(getNextElementPlease, sentinel):
    ...
```

where `sentinel` is whatever value you're expecting to terminate the loop. Probably something like `None`. The iterator will call `getNextElementPlease` to get elements and stop when `getNextElementPlease` returns the sentinel value.

Comment: You can also define a `class AnyFalseValue:` whose `__eq__(self, other)` does `return not other`. Then using `iter(func, AnyFalseValue())` will be 100% equivalent of the `if not i: break`, catching both `None`, `False`, `0`, empty sequences etc.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Doable, but at that point, it's probably clearer to switch to `while True`/`break`, or to write your own generator that calls an input function and stops when that function returns a false value.

Answer (score 8):

Currently, the least repetitive version of this pattern (and often seen) is the following:

```
while True:
    i = getNextElementPlease()
    if not i:
        break
    print(i)
```

Looking ahead, however, Python 3.8 will introduce **assignment expressions** via [pep-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics) which will allow:

```
while i := getNextElementPlease():
    print(i)
```