# Perform a function on result of another function if not none

Tags: python, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I have a small snippet of code with two functions in it. 
I want to call the first function if it receives a response then perform a function on that response. Then assign the result to another variable.

In a verbose way it looks like:

```
result = get_something()
if result:
    answer = transform(result)
```

alternatively I could do

```
if get_something():
    answer = transform(get_something())
```

but that requires calling the first function twice

is there a way to do all of this on one line a bit like a ternary (maybe as a lambda)

```
answer = transform(result) if get_something() else None
```

Obviously in the above there is nothing to state what result is but I need to say basically where `result = get_something()`

I can do that in a list comprehension but that seems a bit dumb

```
   answer = [transform(x) for x in [get_something()] if x][0]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we have assignment in a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603956/can-we-have-assignment-in-a-condition)

Comment: So the `answer` should stay undefined when `get_something()` returns None?

Comment: @ababak yes, well not undefined it should be None

Comment: that's wrong: 1) one-lier will not make your case to be more readable 2) you don't have to call first function twice 3) and `answer` should not stay undefined in case of any potential references to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest Python version ([Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html)) there's a new assignment that may be useful for you, `:=`:

> There is new syntax `:=` that assigns values to variables as part of a larger expression. It is affectionately known as “walrus operator” due to its resemblance to the eyes and tusks of a walrus.

```
if (n := len(a)) > 10:
    print(f"List is too long ({n} elements, expected <= 10)")
```

> In this example, the assignment expression helps avoid calling len() twice:

Answer (score 2):

We can in **Python 3.8** with [assignment expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions):

```
if (result := get_something()) is not None:
    # do something with result
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't fully understand the reasons for doing things this way (which is **less clear than any of the others**), here's an example using *lambda*:

> ```py
> >>> def get_something(flag):  # Added the flag argument, to mimic different return values
> ...     return 5 if flag else None
> ...
> >>> answer = (lambda func, arg: func(arg) if arg else None)(int, get_something(True))
> >>> answer
> 5
> >>> answer = (lambda func, arg: func(arg) if arg else None)(int, get_something(False))
> >>> answer
> >>>
> ```