# Is there a Walrus operator in PHP?

Tags: php

In **Python3.8** There is new operator called walrus (`:=`) which can assign new variables inside a condition. I write a simple TCP socket connection in PHP, and I want my program to look nicer.

Is there something similar to it in **PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor** ?

```
if ($data := socket_read ($socket, 1024)) {
     echo $data;
}
```

Comment: Not called Walrus but same functionality. Just remove `:`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How does this differ from the very usual `=` assignment?

Comment: @NicoHaase I didn't know that we can assign elements in a condition with the `=` operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works if the return value of `socket_read()` is "thruthy" or "falsy".

Falsy is `''`, `0`, `[]`, `null` or `false`.

Truthy is anything else.

```php
if ( $data = socket_read($socket, 1024) ) {
     echo $data;
}
```

And if you want to be more specific you can even do the following (credits to @Benni):

```php
if ( 'foo' === $data = socket_read($socket, 1024) ) {
    echo 'data equals foo';
}
```

Or

```php
if ( is_array($data = socket_read($socket, 1024) ) {
    var_dump($data);
}
```

Your example might throw an exception if you are not sure `socket_read()` returns a `string`.

In that case you can do the following:

```php
if ( is_string($data = socket_read($socket, 1024)) ) {
     echo $data;
}
```

For more information about PHP boolean behaviour see
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: ... and when you want to be more specific, you can extend your expression like this:  `if ('foo' === $data = socket_read($socket, 1024)) { ...` or even  `if (is_array($data = socket_read($socket, 1024)) { ...`

Comment: Thanks @Benni. I added the examples to the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd try and add a bit more context to this, maybe someone else will find it useful in future.

The reason PHP doesn't have (or more importantly, *need*) a walrus operator is that in PHP, the assignment operator `=` is both a statement **and** an expression.

When you write

```
$var = 'foo';
```

not only are you assigning the value **foo** to `$var`, but the statement as a whole evaluates to it:

```
php > var_dump($var = 'foo');
string(3) "foo"
```

Using `=` in a PHP condition isn't some magical overriding of the operator in that context, it's just a natural side effect of the fact that an assignment is also an expression.

In Python, this isn't the case. The assignment operator (again, `=`) is *only* a statement. It doesn't itself have a result, and so can't be used in a condition. The walrus operator was added in v3.8 (as mentioned in the question), as a way to bridge that gap. There's a lot more discussion about this in the questions [Can we have assignment in a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603956/can-we-have-assignment-in-a-condition) and [“:=” syntax and assignment expressions: what and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297704/syntax-and-assignment-expressions-what-and-why).